# Setting text label in UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a basic collection view that is a colored grid. All I want to do is add a text label inside in grid cell. In my storyboard I have dragged a label inside the content view of the cell. I've created an outlet for this label inside the view controller that controls the whole collection. But somehow I can't set the text of the cells inside this view controller. What do I need to do?

```
import UIKit
let reuseIdentifier = "CellIdentifer";

class WordsViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var cellView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout methods
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
    {

        return 4;
    }
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
    {

        return 1;
    }


    //UICollectionViewDatasource methods
    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 100
    }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as UICollectionViewCell

        cell.backgroundColor = self.randomColor()

        return cell
    }


    // custom function to generate a random UIColor
    func randomColor() -> UIColor{
        let red = CGFloat(drand48())
        let green = CGFloat(drand48())
        let blue = CGFloat(drand48())
        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`created an outlet for this label inside the view controller` you can't do that if you want to have a text in each cell. What you want to do instead is to subclass UICollectionViewCell (e.g. CustomCollectionViewCell). Set the collectionViewCell in the Storyboard to this Class and connect the label. Now you can set text like this:

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as CustomCollectionViewCell

    cell.backgroundColor = self.randomColor()
    cell.myShinyNewTextLabel.text = "myCustomText"
    return cell
}
```